# ListView getChildCount() return 1 when rotate

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, screen-orientation

I have used about 4 hours to solve problem, but i can't. I want my `ListView` item do something in `onConfigurationChanged`.
I first do follow thing.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

and my `Activity` implementation `onConfigurationChanged`, my `Fragment` also do it.
Finally i implement `onConfigurationChanged` in my `ListView` item.All Activity and Fragment will invoke `onConfigurationChanged` when screen from portrait to landscape, but it won't invoke in `ListView` item. I custom a `ListView` and implement `dispatchConfigurationChanged`, and i find getChildCount will return 1 in `dispatchConfigurationChanged`. Because my ListView item is 2 and 3, so `onConfigurationChanged` won't invoke. But how can i solve it? I have search a long time , but i can't solve.[image]

Comment: @ChristopheCVB but Adapter can't make ListView item invoke onConfigurationChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ask the `Adapter` attached to the `ListView`, he knows better ;)

The `ListView` has only one child, a `LinearLayout`, that's why.

Comment: But i need do something in ListView item's onConfigurationChanged. it will be invoked from dispatchConfigurationChanged.

Comment: Ask `adapter.getCount()` instead of `listview.getChildCount()`.

Comment: how can i get item? finally item.dispatchConfigurationChanged(newConfig), can you give me an example?

Comment: Why not simply implement the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` of your custom `itemView` ?

Comment: i do it, but it will be invoked by ListView's dispatchConfigurationChanged

Comment: only if the itemview is the first, the onConfigurationChanged will invoke

Comment: Are the others visible too ?

Comment: This is my fault.I have two Layout in my RelativeLayout.one below another. the above will be MATCH_PARENT when rotate to landscape, so it will return 1.

Comment: But it still can not solve my problem.Only a way to get ItemView by getView?